# Display the current time and date in an Android application

Tags: android, datetime, android-date

How do I display the current date and time in an Android application?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Okay, not that hard as there are several methods to do this. I assume you want to put the current date & time into a `TextView`.

```
String currentDateTimeString = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

// textView is the TextView view that should display it
textView.setText(currentDateTimeString);
```

There is more to read in the documentation that can easily be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28%29)
. There you'll find more information on how to change the format used for conversion.

Comment: Please - be more explicit! What's the error? Did you import the wrong DateFormat class? It's `java.text.DateFormat` and NOT `android.text.format.DateFormat`! And it's `java.util.Date` and NOT `java.sql.Date`!

Just a little hint on asking questions: try to be precise, e.g.: declare what you mean by "display" in your question. And when you type in my lines - both Date and DateFormat must, of course, be imported - if there's a choice of 2 for each, the least you could try is any combination: it's just 4!

Comment: sorry sir, i got date not time.similarly can we get time ?

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html - there you can see how to define **exactly** what you want to be in your output string. E.g. for time use `"HH:mm:ss"`! Completely: `currentTimeString = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());`

Comment: There's also `DateFormat.getTimeInstance()` and `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()`.

Comment: How efficient is this? Let's say you need to get time from a constantly firing method. Is there anything more efficient than creating a new Date object each time?

Answer (score 126):

```
public class XYZ extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        // formattedDate have current date/time
        Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      // Now we display formattedDate value in TextView
        TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
        txtView.setText("Current Date and Time : "+formattedDate);
        txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        txtView.setTextSize(20);
        setContentView(txtView);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N (24).

Comment: How  to declare `SimpleDateFormat` because I have got  can not find symbol class

Answer (score 52):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Thread myThread = null;

    Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
    myThread= new Thread(runnable);   
    myThread.start();

}

public void doWork() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                TextView txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbltime);
                    Date dt = new Date();
                    int hours = dt.getHours();
                    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                    String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                    txtCurrentTime.setText(curTime);
            }catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
}


class CountDownRunner implements Runnable{
    // @Override
    public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                try {
                doWork();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harshit this function comes with the Android SDK as long as your class extends Activity

Comment: I know this is old question, but if somebody will find it in google like me, he should know that the methods Date.getX are deprecated.

Answer (score 42):

The obvious choices for displaying the time are the [`AnalogClock` View](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/AnalogClock.html) and the [`DigitalClock` View](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html).

For example, the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <AnalogClock
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <DigitalClock 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: dear sir, i want to display current time using setText.

Comment: I feel like a stupid shit after reading this obvious answer! I implemented my own runnable, putting it to sleep for a given amount of time and so on when the obvious answer was a XML-one-liner! Many thanks (more than a year after your post) :-)

Comment: In 2015 it's deprecated and It is recommended you use TextClock instead. :)

Comment: AnalogClock is deprecated in API level 23. and AnalogClock and DigitalClock only show current time, but not current date.

Answer (score 36):

In case you want a single line of code:

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

The result is `"2016-09-25 16:50:34"`

Answer (score 22):

My own working solution:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

String sDate = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" 
+ c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
+ "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) 
+ " at " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
+ ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wonder why c.get(Calendar.MONTH) returns 5 when it is supposedly 6? My device has correct time settings.

Comment: Oh yeah, but why do they have to do that when the other variables were accurate. :)

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
          int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
          String sDate = month + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

that works fine

Answer (score 20):

If you want to get the date and time in a specific pattern you can use

```
Date d = new Date();
CharSequence s = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", d.getTime());
```

Answer (score 14):

From [How to get full date with correct format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054945/how-to-get-full-date-with-correct-format):

Please, use

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(Context context)
android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(Context context)
```

to get valid time and date formats in sense of current user settings (12/24 time format, for example).

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

private void some() {
    final Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    textView.setText(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this/*Context*/).format(t.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is the code which worked for me. Please try this. It is a simple method which takes time and date from a system call.

```java
public static String getDatetime() {
    Calendar c = Calendar .getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mms");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    return formattedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
String time = hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;


int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

// Assuming that you need date and time in a separate
// textview named txt_date and txt_time.

txt_date.setText(date);
txt_time.setText(time);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Use `formattedDate` as your `String` filled with the date.
In my case: `mDateButton.setText(formattedDate);`

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you're best off with the TextClock widget. It handles all of the complexity for you and will respect the user's 12/24hr preferences.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

Answer (score 7):

To display the current date function:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String date = df.format(c.getTime());
Date.setText(date);
```

You must want to import

> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
>   import java.util.Calendar;

You must want to use

```
TextView Date;
Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Date);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
String sDate = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + month+ "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +
"T" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

This will give date time format like
2010-05-24T18:13:00

Answer (score 5):

This would give the current date and time:

```
public String getCurrDate()
{
    String dt;
    Date cal = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    dt = cal.toLocaleString();
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply copy this code and hope this works fine for you.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                    "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("time => " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

String time_str = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

String[] s = time_str.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("date  => " + s[i]);
}

int year_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[0].split("/")[0]);
int month_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[0].split("/")[1]);
int day_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[0].split("/")[2]);

int hour_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[1].split(":")[0]);
int min_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[1].split(":")[1]);

System.out.println("year_sys  => " + year_sys);
System.out.println("month_sys  => " + month_sys);
System.out.println("day_sys  => " + day_sys);

System.out.println("hour_sys  => " + hour_sys);
System.out.println("min_sys  => " + min_sys);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String currentDateandTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentDateandTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You Can try this way

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String strDate = "Current Time : " + mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to work with date/time in android I recommend you to use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which is a version of `java.time.*` package (available starting from API 26 on android) shipped with Java 8 available as a replacement for `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
String date = localDate.format(formatter);
textView.setText(date);
```

Comment: Just to set it straight, I am sure you meant the correct thing: java.time is *built in* from Android API level 26. ThreeTenABP is what you use to get virtually the same functionality *on lower API levels*. So the code can work on both low and high levels.

Comment: And since the question was about displaying date *and time*, for that purpose one may use for example a `ZonedDateTime` instead of `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime` instead of `ofLocalizedDate`. Otherwise the code will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

**For Show Current Date and Time on Textview**

```
    /// For Show Date
    String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
    // textView is the TextView view that should display it
    textViewdate.setText(currentDateString);
    /// For Show Time
    String currentTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    // textView is the TextView view that should display it
    textViewtime.setText(currentTimeString);
```

Check full Code [Android – Display the current date and time in an Android Studio Example with source code](https://faqdroid.com/android-display-current-date-time-android-studio-example-source-code/)

Answer (score 0):

To get current **Time/Date** just use following code snippet:

To use **Time**:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
String strTime = simpleDateFormatTime.format(now.getTime());
```

To use **Date**:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());    
String strDate = simpleDateFormatDate.format(now.getTime());
```

and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String sDate = format.format(date);//31-12-9999
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);//9999
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mMonth = mMonth + 1;//12
int hrs = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//24
int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);//59
String AMPM;
if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0) {
    AMPM = "AM";
} else {
    AMPM = "PM";
}
```