# How to get the current Time

Tags: android

How to get the current time in Android?

When i use

```
int hours = java.sql.Time.this.getHours();
```

i get the error:

```
No enclosing instance of the type Time is accessible in scope
```

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-current-time-and-date-in-android-application

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
int hours = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()).getHours();
```

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis() return long and Time don't have a long argument! sorry but this code is wrong.

Comment: this code is correct, since the question is about java.sql.Time which has an appropriate constructor.

Comment: On Android java.sql.time has no public hours member, and you must use getHours().

Comment: As I said, it does not work. After alt-Enter a pop up menu appears with two choices: "create class", "create inner class"

Comment: getHours() method of Time class is deprecated since API 16.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

public static final int HOUR_OF_DAY 
Since: API Level 1 
Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite sample:

```
Time dtNow = new Time();
dtNow.setToNow();
int hours = dtNow.hour;
String lsNow = dtNow.format("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M");
String lsYMD = dtNow.toString();    // YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS
```

Comment: I think this is faster than `Calendar.getInstance()`. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the current timestamp, you can use:

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

You can also get other time related values such as the uptime or total elapsed time since the last boot (including sleep time) from `android.os.SystemClock`.

Answer (score 2):

The instance of the [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()) Class is set to the current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // get current time in a Calendar`

then you can do lots with the Calendar instance, such as get the Hours or the Minutes - like:

`int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);`

This is recommended when you have to localize to many locales, and print data in multiple formats, or do operations on dates.

Comment: This is currently the best answer as getHours() / getDate() etc have been depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a little to Andrew's reply.  The later part of the code increments the hour if your time zone is in daylight savings mode.  The HOUR_OF_DAY is in 24 hour format.

```
    Calendar currentTime    = Calendar.getInstance()                ;
    int hour                = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) ; 
    int minute              = currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)      ;
    int second              = currentTime.get(Calendar.SECOND)      ;
    long milliDiff          = currentTime.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) ;
    // Got local offset, now loop through available timezone id(s).
    String [] ids           = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()            ;
    for (String id : ids) 
            {
       TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id)                   ;
       if (tz.getRawOffset() == milliDiff)
          {  // Found a match, now check for daylight saving
          boolean inDs    = tz.inDaylightTime(new Date())   ;
          if (inDs)       { hour += 1 ; }
          if (hour == 25) { hour  = 1 ; }
          break                                             ;
          }
        }
```