# How to get smallest time from database table

Tags: android, sqlite, simpledateformat

I have a table that has time column in `yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm` format .I want to get the the time value that is nearest to current time and date.I am able to get the time value that is nearest to current time but not the date.

This is what I am doing

```
    SimpleDateFormat mSDFmSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");//yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm not working
    Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    mSDF.setTimeZone(tz);
    String time = mSDF.format(calSet.getTime());
    Cursor selectedtime = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT " + ALARM_TIME + " FROM "
            + ALARM_TABLE + " WHERE " + ALARM_TIME + " >=  '" + time
            + "' ORDER BY " + ALARM_TIME + " LIMIT 1 ;", null);
```

Every suggestions are welcomed please help me

Comment: I would consider making the time a timestamp instead of String representation, much easier to query against.

Comment: @Shakeeb Shaheen  pls see this link get current time only 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611059/how-to-get-the-current-time/3611122#3611122

Comment: @Carnal can u put it into small demo code for timeStamp to show how to use it for date and time sorting

Comment: @KarthikeyanKarthik time is not a problem a Can get it easily problem is date and time together

Comment: @Shakeeb Shaheen: What I mean is that in your SQLite, store the ALARM_TIME as a timestamp instead of a String. Then you can use System.currentTimeInMillis to get the next alarm.

Comment: @Carnal Ok now I got it

Answer (score 1):

To perform arithmetic on date/time, SQLite provides `JULIANDAY` function which will convert your date into an `FLOAT`.

So,

```
SELECT ABS(JULIANDAY(SUBSTR(alarm_time,1,5)||' '||SUBSTR(alarm_time,-5))-JULIANDAY('NOW')), * FROM alarm_table;
```

will return time diferences (in days) from `alarm_time` to current time.

However, if you only need nearest time in future, simple comparison will suffice:

```
SELECT * FROM alarm_table WHERE alarm_time>=STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M','NOW')
ORDER BY alarm_time LIMIT 1;
```