# How to create a Digital Clock on Android?

Tags: android

I've been trying to write a simple Digital Clock app for Android. First I used the built in Digital Clock and tried to omit the seconds display, but I couldn't. I wanted clock's seconds to trigger some lines of code I have.

Then I start to develop simple application to put Digits on screen but I don't know how to trigger the display in most efficient way. Anybody can give me a simple start, where to look and what functions to use ? How can I execute few lines of code within every second? I tried the example at [Display the current time and date in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-current-time-and-date-in-android-application) but it wasn't successful. There were no libraries by the name CountDownRunner to import.

I am new to android development, however I have fairly good experience in Java, C,C++.

Thank you

Comment: Digital Clock is depreciated above api level 17 its recommended that you uses TextClock and here is its support library which work for me https://github.com/vojtech/android-textclock-backport/branches

Answer (score 9):

Here a simple clock i developed using methods used in android native DigitalClock.java  and AnalogClock.Java classes.**this clock supports for events that triggered for each second or minute**,so you can use those events and run your code.

> 1. StartTickPerSecond() method uses the method used in DigitalClock.java  to get the tick per second.
> 2. StartTickPerMinute() method uses the method used in AnalogClock.java  to get the tick per minute

this  still may require some modifications..but  hope this will be something you to start with..

 
**Clock.java**

```
package com.sample.data;

import java.util.*;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.text.format.Time;
public class Clock 
{
    public static final int TICKPERSECOND=0;
    public static final int TICKPERMINUTE=1;

    private Time Time;
    private TimeZone TimeZone;
    private Handler Handler;
    private List<OnClockTickListner> OnClockTickListenerList = new ArrayList<OnClockTickListner>();

    private Runnable Ticker;

    private  BroadcastReceiver IntentReceiver;
    private IntentFilter IntentFilter;

    private int TickMethod=0;
    Context Context;

    public Clock(Context context)
    {
        this(context, Clock.TICKPERMINUTE); 
    }
    public Clock(Context context,int tickMethod)
    {
        this.Context=context;
        this.TickMethod=tickMethod;
            this.Time=new Time();
        this.Time.setToNow();

        switch (TickMethod)
        {
            case 0:
                this.StartTickPerSecond();
                break;
            case 1:
                this.StartTickPerMinute();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void Tick(long tickInMillis)
    {
        Clock.this.Time.set(Clock.this.Time.toMillis(true)+tickInMillis);
        this.NotifyOnTickListners();
    }
    private void NotifyOnTickListners()
    {
        switch (TickMethod)
        {
            case 0:
                for(OnClockTickListner listner:OnClockTickListenerList)
                {
                    listner.OnSecondTick(Time);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                for(OnClockTickListner listner:OnClockTickListenerList)
                {
                    listner.OnMinuteTick(Time);
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    private void StartTickPerSecond()
    {
        this.Handler=new Handler();
        this.Ticker = new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {           
                Tick(1000);
                long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);           
                Handler.postAtTime(Ticker, next);             
            }
        };
        this.Ticker.run();

    }
    private void StartTickPerMinute()
    {
        this.IntentReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
               Tick(60000);

            }
        };
        this.IntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        this.IntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        this.Context.registerReceiver(this.IntentReceiver, this.IntentFilter, null, this.Handler);

    }
     public void StopTick()
     {
         if(this.IntentReceiver!=null)
         {
             this.Context.unregisterReceiver(this.IntentReceiver);
         }
         if(this.Handler!=null)
         {
             this.Handler.removeCallbacks(this.Ticker);
         }
     }
     public Time GetCurrentTime()
     {
         return this.Time;
     }
    public void AddClockTickListner(OnClockTickListner listner) 
    {
        this.OnClockTickListenerList.add(listner);

    }

}
```

**OnClockTickListner.java**

```
public interface OnClockTickListner {
    public void OnSecondTick(Time currentTime);
    public void OnMinuteTick(Time currentTime);
}
```

**How to use**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.clock_list_item);
        Clock c=new Clock(this);
        c.AddClockTickListner(new OnClockTickListner() {

            @Override
            public void OnSecondTick(Time currentTime) {
                Log.d("Tick Test per Second",DateFormat.format("h:mm:ss aa ", currentTime.toMillis(true)).toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void OnMinuteTick(Time currentTime) {
                Log.d("Tick Test per Minute",DateFormat.format("h:mm aa", currentTime.toMillis(true)).toString());

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the source code for the [DigitalClock](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/DigitalClock.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/widget/DigitalClock.java&l=1) widget. In particular, look at the `onAttachedToWindow()` method which creates a Runnable to handle the 1 second 'ticks'.