# How to get full date with correct format?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the date.

I am using this for the date and month

```
int date = cld.get(Calendar.DATE);
int month = cld.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Instead of it returning as a int i want it to be a string. or maybe the full date format.

Such as: 12/12/12 
or...

August 14 2011

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to learn about `SimpleDateFormat`.

The basics for getting the current time in ISO8601 format:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
String now = df.format(new Date());
```

For other formats:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
String now = df.format(new Date());
```

or

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
String now = df.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks i know about simpleDateFormat. Just didnt think to use it Thanks alot

Answer (score 5):

Please, use

android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(Context context)
android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(Context context)

to get valid time and date formats in sense of current user settings (12/24 time format, for example).

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

private void some() {
    final Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    textView.setText(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this/*Context*/).format(t.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get date as your desire as below

```
Date date = new Date();
String string = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", date.getTime());
```

You can replace this (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) as your desire for example(yy-MM-dd hh:mm)

Answer (score 0):

You can get full Date in one line:

```
String string = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new Date().getTime());
```

You can use this link for more formats :

- [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)
- [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)