# Calendar giving me the wrong hour and minute

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to get the time of a timestamp but I keep getting the wrong time when I use `Calendar.HOUR` and `Calendar.MINUTE`,no matter what the timestamp is it tells me the hour is 10 and the minute is 12.

now when I use the `Calendar.getTime()` it gives me the correct time so I dont understand? I just want to get the hour in 12hr format and the minute

here is how i go about doing it

```
public static String getRealTime(long time){

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.d("Calendar",String.valueOf(time));
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    Date timeS = cal.getTime();
    String sTime = timeS.toString(); // gives correct time in 24hr format
    int hr = cal.HOUR;               // gives me 10 no matter what the timestamp is
    int min = cal.MINUTE;            // gives me 12 no matter what the timestamp is
    String dMin = getDoubleDigit(min);
    int ampm = cal.AM_PM;
    String m = new String();
    if(ampm == 0){
        m = "AM";
    }else{
        m="PM";
    }
    String rtime = String.valueOf(hr)+":"+dMin+" "+m;
    return rtime;
}
```

so say the timestamp is `1316626200000` cal.getTime() gives me `Wed Sep 21 13:30:00 EDT 2011` which would be the correct time but `cal.HOUR` gives me `10` for the hour which clearly is not what it should be. Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cal.HOUR` and `cal.MINUTE` are static final Integers for use in `Calendar` method calls.  You would use this code to get the correct result:

```
   int hr = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
   int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Notice that I called the `HOUR` and `MINUTE` fields from `Calendar` and not your object `cal`. It is bad practice to call static members from an instantiated object.

Answer (score 2):

The great and almighty Android Reference page to the rescue!!! :D http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

So, here's the lowdown on why some of those things aren't returning the results you are expecting. First off, the Calendar.HOUR is not a reference to the current hour. First hint at that is the fact that it is in all caps, which by Java convention means that this is a constant (aka `final`) field. If you are developing in Eclipse it probably brought up a warning saying that you should probably reference the static variable with the class name `Calendar` instead of using the instance `cal`. Second hint: the reference page said so! ;)

Well, what should you do with the `Calendar.HOUR` then? That is a static constant so that you can use the `cal.get()` to find out. (see the reference page http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int))

But! There is an easier way. The code that you might be looking for could be something like this:

```
public static String getRealTime(long time){
    return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(time));
    //if you'd rather have the current time, just use new Date() without the time as a parameter
}
```

Another user has asked for a sorta similar things and there are a few other implementations on this page [Display the current time and date in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-current-time-and-date-in-android-application)

Comment: Poo, I take too long to write my answers! :D