# how to get the current date of android phone?

Tags: android, date

This is how i get the phone's date, but it prompts me with a parseException, what's the problem?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    Date localDate = sdf.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Date(0)` is not the current date/time. You should use `new Date()`. ParseException should go away then. If you wanna know why you got that, simply debug your program and have a look at what new Date(0) gives as a String, you'll know why it fails to be parsed.

```
Date now = new Date();
Date alsoNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String nowAsString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now);
```

That works. And that too:

```
Date christmas = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-12-25");
```

By the way, make sure you are using `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date`

Comment: i guess the error is that i want to get a Date type, not String

Comment: i m using java.util.Date... did you try that code i pasted there?

Comment: i copied your Date christmas = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-12-25"); to my project, it prompts the same error...

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
String nowDate = formatter.format(now.getTime());
String[] separateCurrentDate = nowDate.split("-");
String year = separateCurrentDate[0];
String month = separateCurrentDate[1];
String day = separateCurrentDate[2];
int currentYear = Integer.parseInt(year);
int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(month);
int currentDay = Integer.parseInt(day);
```

and then store y,m,d one by one into a Date type onject

Answer (score 1):

```
 Date now = new Date();
   Date alsoNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
   String nowAsString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(now);
   currentdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textcntdate);
   currentdate.setText(nowAsString);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Date dt = new Date();
                    int hours = dt.getHours();
                    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                    String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

And then also here is another link on this
[Display the current time and date in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-the-current-time-and-date-in-an-android-application)

Comment: -1 because all those methods are deprecated. Either use a Calendar to get separate fields or use a DateFormat to format a date.