# Get Time when Video was Recorded (Android)

Tags: android, video, timestamp

is there any way to get the a video's exact recording date in milliseconds?
I use this sample code for making the video.
[How can I capture a video recording on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android)

Is there any way to extract that information?
And I'm talking about when the video was started! Not when the file was created...
Is there a way to insert the time?
The generall idea is that my colleagues can use the video as well, without the need of deserialising some class where the timeinformation is stored.

Edit
For example I get the video from a colleague and then want to determinate when the video was recorded.

Bye
JackZ

Comment: did you wrote the video on the Sdcard?

Comment: yes i wrote the video to the Sdcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample here, taken from the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-the-current-time-and-date-in-an-android-application):

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    // formattedDate have current date/time
    Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Also, you can check the [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) or you can just:

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Call this one wherever you need and record the value.

**EDIT**

To extract the information from the file itself try [this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) and more specifically [this one](http://pads162.cs.nthu.edu.tw/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#METADATA_KEY_DATE).

Comment: Sry but I want to extract this Information out of the video not generate it myself...
For example I get the video from a colleague and then want to determinate when the video was recorded.

Comment: thank you very much! I would like to give you reputation but I'm not allowed to ;(

Comment: Don't worry about that, the main thing is that the code snippet did its job ;-)

Comment: @JackZ I am using the property MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DATE to get the timestamp, but this does not give me time precision in milliseconds. which property did you use?