# Can't find getDateTimeInstance method in android ADT

Tags: android, datetime

I am a newer to Android development. now I want to show current system time in a thread via textview control. I get some example and can start the thread to draw text in textview control.

but when I trid to get system current time via below link:[Display the current time and date in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-the-current-time-and-date-in-an-android-application), I got errors,The error saying:getDateTimeInstance() is undefined for the type DateFormat.
Why this answer didn't work for me ? thx.

below is the code for your reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView timeView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
                System.out.println("Thread is running!!");
                timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                timeView.setText("I am Fired via Non-UI thread:"+s);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: put your code which you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updatin ui in a thread not possible

```
 timeView.setText("I am Fired via Non-UI thread:"+s);
```

Use `runOnUiThread`. Inside thread's run method

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       timeView.setText("I am Fired via Non-UI thread:"+s);
                    }
                });
```

Also initialize textview in outside the thread

```
     timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)
```

Also check this

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html

Check your import statement.

```
import java.text.DateFormat // import this
```

instead of

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
```

Comment: is this the usual way to solve this? ain't this producing more traffic on main-ui?

Comment: @bofredo why would it be. if you are doing background computation do it on a thread only update ui on the ui thread or use asynctask

Comment: He is correct, you cannot update the Android UI from a separate thread so you have to use a handler or runOnUiThread for the actual interface updates.

Comment: thx for your reference. but now the "new Date()" throws me exception: the constructor Date() is undifined.

Comment: @CharlieShi have you imported `import java.util.Date` cross check your imports again

Comment: Have trid import java.util.Date, but still throws me the same exception as above.

Comment: @CharlieShi i don't see any reason why it should not if you do it right. My guess is you have the wrong imports.